# csv import to manytomanyfield Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I used below code to import csv file to django model containing manytomanyfield  Release.metamodules

```
>>> from app.models import Metamodule,Release
>>> reldata = csv.reader(open('/root/Django-1.6.5/django/bin/dashboard/release.csv'),delimiter=',')

for row in reldata:
  q = Release(number = row[0],
      notes= row[1],
      changes = row[2],
      metamodules = Metamodule.objects.filter(name = row[3]))

  try:
      q.save()
  except:
     # if the're a problem anywhere, you wanna know about it
     print "there was a problem with line"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 5, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 416, in    __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" %   list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'metamodules' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

As the field is ManyToManyField i used objects.fileter to get multiple records. But it is returning error.Please help me to fix this issue

models.py:

```
class Metamodule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    modulename = models.ForeignKey(Module)
    createdate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    createdby = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.name)


class Release(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    changes = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    metamodules = models.ManyToManyField(Metamodule)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.number)
```

Comment: Please adjust your formatting *exactly* as it appears in your `models.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create your Release object like that. You cannot create m2m relations from unsaved objects. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Try something like this :

```
for row in reldata:
    q = Release(number=row[0], notes=row[1], changes=row[2])
    # You have to save the object before adding the m2m relations
    q.save()

    metamodules = Metamodule.objects.filter(name=row[3])    
    for metamodule in metamodules:
        q.metamodules.add(metamodule)
```

There is probably a better way to do the for loop but this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: That should be nested for loop rite?

Comment: Yes sorry I edited my answer. Please mark the answer as accepted if it did solve your problem.

Comment: How about the csv import if I use ForeignKey instead of ManyToManyField there?

Comment: You can just create your object like this:
    metamodule = Metamodule.objects.get(name=row[3])) then
    q = Release(number=row[0], notes=row[1], changes=row[2], metamodule=metamodule)